# Dark shading on glass material - EEVEE

Tags: objects, eevee-render-engine, glass, shader-nodes

I followed this YouTube tutorial on how on how to create a glass material with Eevee. (https://youtu.be/JYyUMMboZFk)

After following the tutorial step by step, I realised there is this dark shading on the top of my object - a smoothie cup container.[image]
[image]
[image]

Now moving farther away from the cup, the shading seemed to disappear.[image]

But it still shows in the final rendered file.[image]
[image]

How do I get rid of the Dark Shading?

Comment: I remember looking at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYyUMMboZFk for a real nice realistic glass shader without all the weird stuff.

Comment: @AnsonSavage Apparently, it is the same video tutorial I was following, but after watching it again, I found the adjustment. Thanks 

Answer (score 2):

I eventually fixed the shading.

- Select on the object with the dark shading
- Head over to the *Material* tab on the *Properties Window*.
- Scroll down to *Settings*
- Make sure *Screen Space Refraction* is toggled on
- Increase refraction from 0m to 0.1m

Bonus: Make sure to reduce the roughness of the material

[image]